# Any binary linear code of block length $4$ do not attain the hamming bound

Tags: coding-theory

There does not exist any binary linear code with block length $4$ that achieves the hamming bound.

---

I am unable to proceed at all. Please provide me some hint.

Comment: Well as a hint, the Hamming bound involves dividing one number ($2^n$) by another ($\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{(d-1)/2\rfloor}}{n \choose k}$, where $d$ is the min distance). Are you able to show that those numbers don't work (i.e. it wouldn't be an integer?)

Comment: @M.McIlree : Here nothing is said about $d$. We can tell $0 \le d \le 3$. Can we say something more about $d$?

Comment: That's only 4 values to check I suppose? And it looks like you can immediately rule out $d = 0$ and $d=1$ (hamming bound doesn't even make sense in those cases)?

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^t \binom{4}{i}$ is the hamming bound. You can see that $t$ is either 0 or 1(Use the minimum distance). So, the size of the code is either 1 or 5. Since it is linear and 5 is not a power of 2, it is not possible. That means, the only code you can have is the zero code.